# Side-by-side bar chart with columns proportional by group (relative frequency bar chart)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

The dataset

```
gender <- c('Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female')
answer <- c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes')
df <- data.frame(gender, answer)
```

is biased towards females:

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(gender, fill = gender)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

My task is to build a graph that makes it easy to figure out which of the two genders is more likely to say `'Yes'`.

But, given the bias, I cannot just do

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = answer, fill = gender)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

or even

```
df %>% ggplot(aes(x = answer, y = ..count../sum(..count..), fill = gender)) +
geom_bar(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

To alleviate the bias I need to divide each of the counts by the total number of males or females respectively so that the `'Female'` bars add up to `1` as well as the `'Male'` ones. Like so:

```
df.total <- df %>% count(gender)
male.total <- (df.total %>% filter(gender == 'Male'))$n
female.total <- (df.total %>% filter(gender == 'Female'))$n

df %>% count(answer, gender) %>% 
mutate(freq = n/if_else(gender == 'Male', male.total, female.total)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = answer, y = freq, fill = gender)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Which draws a completely different picture.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a way to simplify the former piece of code using only `dplyr` and `ggplot2`?
2. Are there any other libraries that can do the trick better?
3. Does the above type of chart have a conventional name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1:

```
df %>%  
  count(gender, answer) %>% 
  group_by(gender) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = answer, y = freq, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')
```

Question 2:

You can probably do it in fewer lines with other packages.

Question 3:

Relative frequency bar graph.

Answer (score 2):

Given the data, the most effective way to determine whether men or women are more likely to answer "yes" to the question asked is to convert the data to a binary variable and run a difference of proportions test.

```
gender <- c('Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female')
answer <- c('Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes')
isYes <- ifelse(answer=="Yes",1,0)

t.test(isYes ~ gender)
```

...and the output:

```
> t.test(isYes ~ gender)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  isYes by gender
t = -0.34659, df = 14.749, p-value = 0.7338
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5965761  0.4299094
sample estimates:
mean in group Female   mean in group Male 
           0.4166667            0.5000000
```

The `t.test()` output provides the same percentages of `yes` as the weighted frequency chart, but the p-value from the test statistic indicates that we should accept the null hypothesis that there is no difference between men and women in their likelihood to answer `yes` to the question asked.

Another way to interpret the `t.test()` output is that since 0 is within the 95% confidence interval of the difference of means, we fail to reject the null hypothesis that the means of the two groups are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer although the question was purely about graphs. Sorry for the misleading formulation. Changed it.

Comment: @ageorge - I understood that your question was about graphs, however, the commentary about "which gender is more likely to say yes" requires a statistical answer as the chart is misleading without it. That is, the chart indicates men are more likely to say `yes` when the t-test says that the difference is not statistically significant.

Answer (score 2):

`position = "fill"` in `geom_bar` is useful for seeing relative proportions:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(gender = c("Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female"), 
                 answer = c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(gender, fill = answer)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill')
```

[image: proportion plot]