# Relative Frequency Barchart doesn't add to 1 -- geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to create a relative frequency bar chart for race and education. So, for example, the relative frequency for Asians with a Bachelor's degree should be the number of Asians with a bachelor's degree, divided by the sum of Asians in the dataframe.

My code is below, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434062/side-by-side-bar-chart-with-columns-proportional-by-group-relative-frequency-ba). But I can't figure out why my relative frequencies aren't summing to 1. There aren't any NA's in the data, so I'm a little baffled.

```
df %>%  
  count(racecen, maxedu) %>% 
  group_by(racecen) %>% 
  mutate(freq = n/sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = maxedu, y = freq, fill = racecen)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

I'm not sure whether this is a data issue or a syntax issue (forgive the amateurnish). I want to  believe that it's a syntax issue, but the syntax seems like it should work. If it's a data problem, what kinds of general errors in the data could cause this?

**EDIT**
`dput(df)`:

```
structure(list(racecen = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
1L), .Label = c("Asian", "Black", "Hispanic", "White"), class = "factor"), 
    maxedu = structure(c(5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 
    3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 
    5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 
    6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 2L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
    3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
    3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
    7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 
    6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
    6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
    3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 5L), .Label = c("maxhs", "maxas", "maxba", "maxpostundergrad", 
    "maxma", "maxpostgrad", "maxphdjd"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3191L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your relative frequency should sum to 1 for each race. Can you update your post with `dput(df)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah updated! It's ~3000 observations

Comment: well, it seems to work fine for me but I think you have `plyr` loaded along with `dplyr`. Can you restart R, load only `dplyr`, `ggplot2` and try this? Or use `dplyr::count(racecen, maxedu)`, `dplyr::mutate(freq = n/sum(n))` explicitly mentioning the package name.

Comment: Dang, that worked. I can't believe that was it. Thank you! Mad at this ```plyr/dplyr``` mess